# How to pass List of objects which again contains List of objects from one activity to another in Android

Tags: java, android

Below given class, List of which i want to pass to another activity.
List health;(How to parcel List of this class)

```
public class HealthDiagnosis  {

    @SerializedName("Issue")
    private DiagnosedIssue issue;

    @SerializedName("Specialisation")
    private List<DiagnosedSpecialisation> specialisation;

    public DiagnosedIssue getIssue() {
        return issue;
    }

    public void setIssue(DiagnosedIssue issue) {
        this.issue = issue;
    }

    public List<DiagnosedSpecialisation> getSpecialisation() {
        return specialisation;
    }

    public void setSpecialisation(List<DiagnosedSpecialisation> specialisation) {
        this.specialisation = specialisation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't capitalise variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parcel any complex objects simply, use this site :http://www.parcelabler.com/

just put your classe there. then generate the parcelled class. Copy it to your project. Do this for all the three classes one by one..

then use `putExtra` of `intent` to pass the parent object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);  
intent.putExtra("Key", healthDiagnosis);
startActivity(intent);
```